# Are the left and right unitor maps of the unit object in a monoidal category the same?

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Suppose we have a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category) $\mathbb{C}$, with monoidal product $\otimes$, monoidal unit $I$, left unitor components $I \otimes A \overset{\lambda_A}{\rightarrow} A$ and right unitor components $A \otimes I \overset{\rho_A}{\rightarrow} A$. In this case is it true that $\lambda_I = \rho_I$? If so what is the proof?

Comment: Yes, it is true. This follows from the coherence theorem for monoidal categories. A concrete proof is given, for example, in Lemma 1.5 of Kock's [Elementary remarks on units in monoidal categories](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0507349).